# configure traefik as reverse proxy with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I am trying to configure traefik to connect between my 3 docker containers.
I tried with this configuration but I got net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED on my browser console.

```
  searchservice:
    hostname: searchservice
    image: searchservice:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT
    container_name: searchservice
    networks:
      - es-network 
          #ipv4_address: 172.21.0.12
    ports:
      - 8070:8080
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - reverseproxy
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/searchservice,Host:localhost"
      - "traefik.port: 8070"
      - "traefik.enable=true"

  subscriber-service:
    hostname: subscriber-service
    image: subscriberservice:0.0.4-SNAPSHOT
    container_name: subscriber-service

    networks:
      - es-network 
          #ipv4_address: 172.21.0.13
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongo1
      - mongo2
      - reverseproxy
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/api,Host:localhost"
      - "traefik.port: 8090"
      - "traefik.enable=true"

  searchappfront:
    hostname: searchappfront
    image: frontservice:latest
    container_name: searchappfront
    networks:
      - es-network 
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - subscriber-service
      - searchservice
      - reverseproxy
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=80"
     # - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:localhost"

  reverseproxy:
    image: traefik:v2.1
    command:
      - '--providers.docker=true'
      - '--entryPoints.web.address=:80'
      - '--providers.providersThrottleDuration=2s'
      - '--providers.docker.watch=true'
      - '--providers.docker.defaultRule=Host("local.me")'
      - '--accessLog.bufferingSize=0'
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro'
    #ports:
    #  - '80:80'
    #  - '8080:8080'
```

The searchappfront is an angular application where the http endPoints have this pattern

```
http://subscriber-service:8090/
http://searchservice:8070/
```

if I use localhost instead of hostnames, requests work fine but I need to deploy these containers in a cloud instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using traefik 2, but your annotation is for traefik 1. This is not going to work.